# Wordpress menu items are showing as ID not url slug

Tags: wordpress

Normally my Wordpress menu items show as the slug i.e **'/about-us'** .
For some reason they are instead showing as **'/?page_id=8913'**
Does anyone know how to change them to the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

I've answered my own question but just to help anyone else out. Just go to the settings/permalinks from the wordpress menu. You can change the format of the urls from there.